# How to do curve_fit in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I need to curve fit a set of data using y = x / (a + x), where a is the parameter that I am required to get from this excercise.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x = [1, 2, 7, 10, 20, 70, 200, 1000]
y = [0, 0, 15.3, 34.6, 49.3, 82.6, 100]
def fit(x, a):
    return x/(a+x)
par, con = curve_fit(fit, x, y)
plt.plot(x, fit(x, par[0]))
plt.show()
```

Using this I get some abomination of a fit. Doesn't even remotely fit.

If I try it like this:

```
def fit(x, a, b):
    return b*x/(a+x)
```

I get a fit but it's without round cornerns. It's just straight lines. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there an error in your data? The length of the arrays do not match!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that your `x` is a `list` of `int`, in `Python` division are by default integer division, which is not what you want here.

Therefore, a few changes will make it work, use the 2nd function as an example, your first function is not going to fit well as it will have a limit of 1 when x->inf:

```
def fit(x, a, b):
    return b*x*1./(a+x)
A, B=curve_fit(fit, x, y)[0]
plt.plot(x, fit(x, A, B))
plt.plot(x, y, 'r+')
plt.savefig('temp.png')
```

[image]

It is a set of straight lines because you only calculate `y` at those `x` values, to get a curve: change the plotting call to `plt.plot(np.linspace(0,200,100), fit(np.linspace(0,200,100), A, B))`
[image]